# Parsing command line arguments through the main function

Tags: command-line-arguments

Is there a way to run multiple C program through one single C source code file using command line argument?

E.g. suppose the executable file is named, testing.out, if in the runtime one wants
the first test, then type “Testing.out 1”, if the second, “Testing.out 2”,
etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be easily done using the command line arguments functionality provided by C.

You can read more about it here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_command_line_arguments.htm

And a lots of other tutorials:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/command-line-arguments-in-c-cpp/
https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson14.html